# Unable to figure out why firebase hosting is not using http 2

Tags: firebase, http2, firebase-hosting

I've set up a fresh hosting project (not using any custom domain at the moment) and split up some of my js files expecting them to be served via http2 (as described in firebase blog posts it should be enabled by default?) However protocol still shows up as http/1.1. Am I missing something? Do I need to add entry in my config files to force http2?

[image]

**DEMO:** https://asimetriq-com.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, see attached screenshot.

It may mean that you have some transparent proxy that does not support HTTP/2 in the network hops from your client to the server.

Also, from time to time, browsers may downgrade the protocol they are using to collect statistics about protocol performances to be able to compare them.

[image: asimetriq on h2]

Comment: Very weird, I'd love to learn more about transparent proxies though, any pointers at what level this could happen, i.e. isp or something?

Comment: Are you using any antivirus product? If so turn it off for HTTPS traffic so it doesn’t MITM traffic.