# Why is my firebase-hosting site not being served by http2?

Tags: http2, firebase-hosting, hugo

My firebase site critical-edge-1@firebaseapp.com is not being served over http/2. Not sure why, all sites are supposed to be.

I am using Hugo site generation. Thoughts?

Comment: Try taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066930/unable-to-figure-out-why-firebase-hosting-is-not-using-http-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to figure out why firebase hosting is not using http 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066930/unable-to-figure-out-why-firebase-hosting-is-not-using-http-2)